# Joi.array().includes is not a function error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, joi

I am validating payload data of my API with Joi validation. I have made one schema like this:

```
'use strict';

let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let tokenSchema = new Schema({

    level : {type : Number},
    tokenValues : [{
        level : {type : Number},
        amount : {type : Number}
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tokens',tokenSchema,'tokens');
```

I have written Joi validation:

```
validate: {
            payload: {
                level: Joi.number().required(),
                tokensValues: Joi.array().includes({
                    level : Joi.number().required(),
                    amount : Joi.number().required()
                })
            }
}
```

This above code is giving error like this :

```
TypeError: Joi.array(...).includes is not a function
```

Please suggest some other method if this is the wrong practice.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution :

```
validate: {
            payload: {
                level: Joi.number().required(),
                tokensValues: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
                    level : Joi.number().required(),
                    amount : Joi.number().required()
                }))
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Joi.types.Array().includes(Joi.types.Array().valid(["pass array strings here"]))
```

if you are using [express-joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-joi)